# npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.1.13

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I try  installing @angular/cli@1.6.4 globally on windows 10 with 64bit,
it produces me this errors   `npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.1.13 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.46 but none was installed.`
and this on  `npm WARN @schematics/schematics@0.0.13 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.46 but none was installed.`

my node version 8.9.4.  npm version 5.6.0 
I installed
 `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` .I removed angular Cli and install it again but in vain the errors still . any help please

Comment: Those are not errors, they are warnings. The term `WARN` in the message indicated that. You can likely proceed without any further issues.

Comment: if so ,why they appear again in creating new project?

Comment: Because the CLI gets installed locally (in the project directory) when you create a new project. You will see warning all the time with npm. Most of the time you can ignore them. The only time(s) you may have to take action is if you really need the dependency it says is missing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll work without it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `npm install --save @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.46`

Comment: Why isn't the devkit installed as a develpoment dependency (`--save-dev`)?

Answer (score 0):

After hours searching for the solution, I found out the problem was on my node version.
Actually I've downloaded the latest one (ver 8.x) and it didn't work. Then, I tried again with an earlier version (ver 6.x, install as normal, it should replace the old one). After I reinstalled nodejs ver 6.x, I try these commands:

**sudo npm install -g @angular/cli**

And it worked.